# Constructor with initialized parameters c++

Tags: c++

I have a declared constructor like this `Foo(int x= 0, int y= 0, int z = 0);`, can this be used as a default constructor too? How does it work? What about the implementation?

Comment: You can create objects like `Foo f` using that constructor, yes. It will set its `x`, `y`, and `z` values to `0`. The implementation of the constructor wouldn't change (although I don't see an implementation of it, so I don't know what it would do exactly).